# Controlling height of box

Tags: boxes

I am currently using the code

```
 \newsavebox{\FVerbB}
\newenvironment{code}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
 \hspace{-0.25cm}
  \begin{lrbox}{\FVerbB}
  \hspace{-0.29cm}
  \begin{BVerbatim}}
 {\end{BVerbatim}
 \hspace{-0.29cm}
  \end{lrbox}
  \fcolorbox{blue!0}{gray!30}{\usebox{\FVerbB}}
  }
```

I have decreased the horizontal size of the box by adding `hspace{-0.29cm}`.  I would like to do something similar for the vertical size of the box...i.e. I would like to include a `vspace{-0.1cm}` somewhere in this code, but I can't figure out where to put it.  Any suggestions?  Thanks so much in advance!

**Update**: the suggestions for the vertical resizing have worked brilliantly.  But I have run into an issue with the box extending too far out in front of the enclosed text. Below is an example.

[image: Current Output]

I don't like that there is no space before the word "is".  Any thoughts on how to fix this?  Thanks so much!

Comment: If I try, I get that the background is too narrow. Can you explain more precisely your goal?

Comment: If you just want to vertically shift the box (as opposed to resizing it), the following substitution will achieve that: `\fcolorbox{blue!0}{gray!30}{\raisebox{0.1cm}{\usebox{\FVerbB}}}`.  If you want to actually resize a box, the `\addvbuffer` macro of the `verbatimbox` package can do that (under certain constraints), but it is not clear, as egreg notes, what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You have some trailing spaces in your code. However, I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{code}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{SaveVerbatim}{VerbEnv}}
 {\end{SaveVerbatim}%
   \fboxsep=1pt   
   \fcolorbox{black}{gray!30}{\BUseVerbatim{VerbEnv}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{code}
fog
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `\colorbox` instead of `\fcolorbox` if you do not want a frame.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply @Herbert!  Your code worked wonderfully.  I do have two questions though: (1) when I use the text box, any spacing that comes immediately after it becomes erased, i.e. `<foo in box> some text` is just `<foo in box>some text`.  (2) Latex gives me an error if I write \begin{code} foo \end{code}.  I have to put \begin{code} and \end{code} on separate lines.  Do you know why this is?  Thanks **so** much for the help though - I'm still new to Latex and Stackexchange, so please forgive me if I have made some obvious mistakes.

Comment: use `\colorbox{gray!30}{\BUseVerbatim{VerbEnv}}\space}`. That depends on how verbatim is read. LaTeX looks for a _line_ with `end{...}`. If you want inline code then use `\verb` or `\lstinline` from package `listings`